# What's the difference between node.js signal server and php daemon signal server

Tags: php, node.js, laravel-5

I need to make a php laravel app that requires web chat and video chat functionality. (I am a beginner so please correct my philosophy if im not right.) So for the client side I'll use webrtc standards but for the server side i am not sure what to do. I have considered 2 options:

### *Nodejs*

I have seen a lot of node.js guides on implementing webrtc through node server. However, come deployment it will require some kind of port routing/forwarding because 2 servers(php + node) cannot occupy a single port which im sure is manageable as well even though i have no idea how in this moment.

### *Php daemon*

The other choice would be a php daemon script which would mean easier deployment. So here are my questions:

1. would the daemon script also take up another port?
2. which one would you choose and why?

Appreciate any help!